# Como pegar índice da coluna selecionada da JTable

Tags: java

Eu tenho uma coluna booleana na minha JTable que é editavel, o que eu quero fazer agora é salvar no banco de dados ao clicar no checkbox da tabela, estou tentando fazer isso no evento de click do mouse entao ao clicar no checkbox verificar se a coluna é a coluna que eu quero que seja editada e se for, salvar no banco de dados, porém não sei como pegar o indice da coluna para fazer essa comparação.

Imagem da JTable

[image: Imagem da Tabela]

Código do evento do click do mouse

```
private void jtPontoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    int colunaSelecionada = jtaApontamentos.getSelectedColumn();
    System.out.println("Coluna selecionada: " + colunaSelecionada); // retorna -1 deveria trazer o indice da coluna selecionada
    if (colunaSelecionada == apTableModel.COLUNA_VERIFICADO) {
        System.out.println("Salvar no banco de dados...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse método retorna -1 quando nenhuma coluna é selecionada, conforme documentação do método. Apresente um código mais completo para que possamos testar e ver porquê está dando isso.

Answer (score -1):

O jeito mas fácil para se fazer isso seria colocando um botão para executar essa ação, quando for acionado ele deve percorrer o JTable e verificar as linhas que estiver com o campo booleano igual a true e inserir no banco.
Sempre quando preciso trabalhar com um JTable realizo a inserção dessa forma.